# Testing two groups of subjects (same population) -> increased replicability?

Tags: sample, replicability

I've seen several experimental psychology papers arguing that, because they separately tested two cohorts of subjects, that this increases the replicability of their finding. Is this really the case? Is replicability not tied by definition to the effect being replicated in whole other testing conditions (different lab, different subject pool etc)?

It is often not mentioned in the paper, but presumably the two separate cohorts are in fact samples from the same population (e.g. the local students), so there is no step towards more external validity (generalisation) of the results.

I'd have thought that proving an effect in cohort1 and finding it again in cohort2 is merely just a form of cross-validation, although only a special case of it (half splitting the sample, or whatever this is called), which I imagine is not as efficient as more thorough forms of cross-validation such as leave-one-out. It would also be more convincing if authors showed that the effect survives regardless of how the total sample is split into two "cohorts", e.g. by doing random permutations.

Any help clarifying these thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Still haven't found an answer for myself to this one, thanks in advance for any replies to this!